# Facebook Handover Protocol : "Page Inbox" not available as Secondary Receiver

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm trying to use the Facebook Handover Protocol with an app connected to a chatbot (made with Rasa), following the [facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/handover-protocol/).
The chatbot is correctly connected to a Page and it's app is subscribed to the webhooks : messages, messaging_postback, messaging_handover and standby

Then I can set the app as primary receiver in the Page settings, but for the Secondary Receiver, "Page Inbox" is not in the list.
If I try to fill nothing for the secondary receiver, I have an error when requesting the Pass Thread Control API.

I would like to allow an operator to respond directly in the inbox rather than having to set up a second app that manages this. I saw many examples where "Page Inbox" is in the list of the secondary receiver and I don't understand why I don't have it..
https://flow.ai/blog/handle-facebook-messenger-handovers

Am I missing something? Is this option subject to EU restrictions or no longer available?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days of unsuccessful research, I gave up hoping to get an answer here or on the Facebook Dev forum.

However this morning when I wanted to try again, I noticed that the "Page Inbox" option mysteriously appeared ...

So I think the main reason could be that I was using a Facebook Page and an app created on the same day and hadn't spent a lot of time setting up the Page.
While waiting for a response to my problem, the only things I have changed are adding a username, profile picture, and banner.

Maybe it was necessary to add these (I am mainly thinking of the page username), maybe we just had to wait for some sort of "verifications" from the facebook side.

This screenshot is from the day this question was written: [No "Page Inbox" option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFTJW.png)
And this one is from today: ["Page Inbox" appeared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrEbP.png)